# Failed to Fetch While Releasing

Tags: ros, ros-release, buildfarm, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Misbehaving Release Binary](http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-jade-rwt-config-generator_binarydeb_utopic_i386/6/console)

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
```

That doesn't seem like my fault! How do I fix it, Masters of the Build Farm™?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218974/failed-to-fetch-while-releasing/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2015-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Utopic is EOL, Canonical just pulled the debs from the default archive. We'll have to switch to old-releases to keep Utopic building. Though we'll probably turn it off soon too.

Ticketed: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm/pull/218

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-10-12**:
Thanks TF™!